# Test case throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring-framework-beans

Below is the error i am getting when i am trying to execute the test case.
It says expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Full error log and the java class is given below.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  ProductServiceTests.testContractService400Response » IllegalState Failed to lo...
  ProductServiceTests.testContractService500Response » IllegalState Failed to lo...
  ProductServiceTests.testInvalidRequestCancelDateFormat » IllegalState Failed t...

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0
```

Given below is the java code. ProductServiceTests.java

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;

import com.cnanational.productservice.controller.ProductServiceController;

public class ProductServiceTests extends ProductServiceApplicationTests{

    @Value(ProductServiceController.PATH_GET_SURCHARGES)
    protected String productSurcharges;

    @Override
    public MockHttpServletRequestBuilder failureTestsRequestBuilder() throws Exception {

        String requestJson = rawJsonFromFile(
                "com/cnanational/productservice/service/valid-request.json");

        System.out.println("the value of surcharges = "+ this.restProperties);

        return post("/surcharges")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, validBasicAuthHeaderValue())
                .header(this.restProperties.getHeaders().getRemoteUser(), USER_NAME)
                .content(requestJson)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    }

    @Test
    public void testInvalidRequestCancelDateFormat() throws Exception
    {
        String requestJson = rawJsonFromFile(
                "com/cnanational/productservice/service/valid-request.json");

        System.out.println("the value of basicAuthHeaderValue111="+ validBasicAuthHeaderValue());

        System.out.println("the value of surcharges = "+ this.restProperties);

        this.mvc.perform(post("/surcharges")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, validBasicAuthHeaderValue())
                .header(this.restProperties.getHeaders().getRemoteUser(), USER_NAME)
                .content(requestJson)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", equalTo(400)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.fields", Matchers.hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.fields[?(@.name == 'cancelDate' && @.code == 'ValidDate')]").exists())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.fields[?(@.name == 'cancelMiles' && @.code == 'Max')]").exists())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
    }

}
----------------------

package com.cnanational.productservice;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.cnanational.productservice.controller.ProductServiceController;
import com.cnanational.servicecommon.config.CommonRestProperties;
import com.cnanational.servicecommon.util.RestUtils;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@EnableWebMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = ProductServiceApplication.class,
        properties = {
            "spring.config.location=classpath:product-service/",
            "spring.config.name=product-service",
            "logging.config=classpath:logback-test.xml"
        })
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles(value = ProductServiceApplication.PROFILE_TEST)
public abstract class ProductServiceApplicationTests
{

    @Autowired
    protected ProductServiceController controller;

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    protected CommonRestProperties restProperties;

    @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    protected RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${security.user.name}")
    protected String username;

    @Value("${security.user.password}")
    protected String password;

    protected static final String USER_NAME = "web_jdoe";

    protected String validBasicAuthHeaderValue()
    {
        return RestUtils.createBasicAuthString(
                username,
                password);
    }

    public abstract MockHttpServletRequestBuilder failureTestsRequestBuilder()
            throws Exception;

    /**
     * Asserts that an upstream 400 response is returned to the client.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testContractService400Response() throws Exception
    {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder failureTestsRequestBuilder = failureTestsRequestBuilder();

        if (failureTestsRequestBuilder == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        String mockedJson = rawJsonFromFile("com/cnanational/productservice/service/invalid-response-400.json");

        ResponseEntity<String> mockedResponse = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .body(mockedJson);

        given(this.restTemplate.exchange(any(), eq(String.class)))
                .willReturn(mockedResponse);

        this.mvc.perform(failureTestsRequestBuilder)
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", equalTo(400)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.code", equalTo(3000)));
    }

    /**
     * Asserts that an upstream 500 response is returned to the client.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testContractService500Response() throws Exception
    {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder failureTestsRequestBuilder = failureTestsRequestBuilder();

        if (failureTestsRequestBuilder == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        String mockedJson = rawJsonFromFile("com/cnanational/productservice/service/invalid-response-500.json");

        ResponseEntity<String> mockedResponse = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body(mockedJson);

        given(this.restTemplate.exchange(any(), eq(String.class)))
                .willReturn(mockedResponse);

        this.mvc.perform(failureTestsRequestBuilder)
            .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", equalTo(500)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.code", equalTo(800004)));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected <T> ResponseEntity<T> mockResponseEntityFromFile(String path, Class<T> responseBodyClass) throws Exception
    {
        String responseJson = rawJsonFromFile(path);

        T responseBody = null;

        if (String.class.equals(responseBodyClass))
        {
            responseBody = (T) responseJson;
        }
        else
        {
            responseBody = this.objectMapper.readValue(
                    responseJson,
                    responseBodyClass);
        }

        ResponseEntity<T> mockedResponse = ResponseEntity.ok(responseBody);

        return mockedResponse;
    }

    protected void testForMultipleStringValues(
            Consumer<UrlWithVariables> function,
            UrlWithVariables ... urlsWithVariables) throws Exception
    {
        for (UrlWithVariables urlWithVariables : urlsWithVariables)
        {
            try
            {
                function.accept(urlWithVariables);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves JSON from a file on the classpath.
     * 
     * @param path
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected String rawJsonFromFile(String path) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(path);
        URI uri = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path).toURI();

        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(uri)));
    }

    public static class UrlWithVariables
    {
        private String url;

        private Object[] variables;

        public UrlWithVariables(String url, Object ... variables)
        {
            this.url = url;
            this.variables = variables;
        }

        public String getUrl()
        {
            return url;
        }

        public Object[] getVariables()
        {
            return variables;
        }
    }

    public static void rethrowException(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action.execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static interface Action
    {
        public void execute() throws Exception;
    }

    public static class FieldNameCodePair
    {
        private String fieldName;

        private String code;

        public FieldNameCodePair(String fieldName, String code)
        {
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
            this.code = code;
        }

        public static FieldNameCodePair from(final String fieldName, final String code)
        {
            return new FieldNameCodePair(fieldName, code);
        }

        public String getFieldName()
        {
            return fieldName;
        }

        public void setFieldName(String fieldName)
        {
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
        }

        public String getCode()
        {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String code)
        {
            this.code = code;
        }
    }
}
```

If any other code base is needed, I will add them to the question. Any inputs are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any class you need to inject must defined at spring container you can do that by add annotation to class declaration "signuture" for example ProductServiceController it should has @Controller at the class signture, check that for all classes.